# Only finite group that acts on even spheres is $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $G$ is acting freely on $\mathbb S^{2n}$ we can associate to $\rho\in G, \rho\neq0$ it's degree $deg\rho=(-1)^{n+1}$ as any map without fixed points has that degree. This shows that every non-trivial element is homotopic to the antipodal map. Why does that imply that $G\subset \mathbb Z_2$?

Comment: The degree should be $(-1)^{2n+1}=-1$. So look at the composition $G\rightarrow\operatorname{Homeo}(X)\rightarrow\{\pm1\}$ (first the action, then the degree). This is a group homomorphism, what can you say about its kernel?

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\{-1, 1\}$ is a group with respect to the standard number multiplication, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

With that we have the following group homomorphism

$$f:G\to\{-1, 1\}$$
$$f(g)=deg(x\mapsto gx)$$

What you've shown is that $f(g)=-1$ for any $g\neq e$. In particular $\ker f=\{e\}$ and thus $f$ is injective.